# nltk quadgram collocation finder

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram, collocation

I am seeing mulitple questions and answers saying that NLTK collocation cannot be done beyond bi and tri grams.

example this one - 
[How to get n-gram collocations and association in python nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672082/how-to-get-n-gram-collocations-and-association-in-python-nltk)

I am seeing that there is a something called

nltk.QuadgramCollocationFinder

Similar to

nltk.BigramCollocationFinder and nltk.TrigramCollocationFinder

But at the same time **cannot** see anything like

nltk.collocations.QuadgramAssocMeasures()

similar to 
nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures() and nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()

What is the purpose of nltk.QuadgramCollocationFinder if its not possible (without hacks) to find n-grams beyond bi and tri grams.

Maybe I am missing something.

Thanks,

Adding in the code and updating the question as per input from Alvas, this now works

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
from nltk.metrics.association import QuadgramAssocMeasures

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures()
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
quadgram_measures = QuadgramAssocMeasures()

the_filter = lambda *w: 'crazy' not in w

finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words(corpus)
finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
finder.apply_ngram_filter(the_filter)
print (finder.nbest(bigram_measures.likelihood_ratio, 10))


finder = QuadgramCollocationFinder.from_words(corpus)
finder.apply_freq_filter(3)
finder.apply_ngram_filter(the_filter)
print(finder.nbest(quadgram_measures.likelihood_ratio,10))
```

Comment: Update your NLTK `pip install -U nltk`, you should be able to get QuadgramAssocMeasures with `from nltk.metrics.association import QuadgramAssocMeasures` https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/metrics/association.py#L298

Comment: thanks a lot Sire ! this now works. Did not have to do the pip install, assuming I already had it. Why is everyone saying though that beyond trigrams does not work ? NLTK got updated with Quadgrams since the other questions on stackoverflow maybe and now NLTK  has Quadgrams also?

Comment: Sire is a little too much for me, call me `alvas` would do ;P . Yes, NLTK has been hugely improved in the past 2-3 years. The `QuadgramCollocationFinder` and the `QuadgramAssocMeasures` is somewhat new. But what the other answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672082/how-to-get-n-gram-collocations-and-association-in-python-nltk is trying to say, is that there is no simple solution to implement a general NgramCollocationFinder, the formula for  `from_words(cls, words)` function is different for every order of ngram.

Comment: Take a look at the contingency table from trigram: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/metrics/association.py#L264 and now take a look at the quadgram: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/metrics/association.py#L321 As the order of ngram increases, the contingency table becomes more complex. And so does the marginal table: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/metrics/association.py#L350

Comment: ok Sire Alvas -;) will call you just Alvas going forward...I will take a look at the github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [repo](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/metrics/association.py#L298):

```
from nltk.metrics.association import QuadgramAssocMeasures
```

Comment: thanks this works as per your suggestion. though can u please let me know why Bi and Trigrams measures are part of nltk.collocations and why QuadgramAssocMeasures are imported from  nltk.metrics.association

Comment: The reason why you can find `BigramAssocMeasures` in `nltk.collocations` is because of the import at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/collocations.py#L39. The true location of the `BigramAssocMeasures` is actually in `nltk.metrics.association`. So it's sort of a feature but not a bug.

Comment: No worries, in 1-2 weeks, the `QuadgramAssocMeasures` should be added to `nltk.collocations` too. There's other more important bugs to fix =)

Comment: so once  QuadgramAssocMeasures move to nltk.collocations...will it work the way it is today, guessing that gets depreciated then ? thx again..

Comment: BTW,just observed that somewhere within the tokenization seems to be spitting punctuations too...so I see ("'", 's', 'really', 'helpful') instead of ("that's", 'really', 'helpful','information')

Comment: The `from nltk.metrics.association import QuadgramAssocMeasures` code will still work after QuadgramAssocMeasures gets added to `nltk.collocations`. It will just be some namespace manipulation so nothing in the NLTK will get deprecated with respect to collocaitons/association measures.

Comment: another example is ('you', "'", 're', 'very') instead of ("you're", 'very','helpful','person')....and one other thing...I thought this removes stopwords...automatically somewhere within the code...but I saw results like ('a', 'helpful')